# Is there a non-web based application for calling in GTalk?

Tags: software-recommendation, voip, google-talk

Is there a option to do this **without** having to use it in **browser** but also have ability to call, not only chat?

Comment: Not to be daft, as I see several answers here. You are referring implicitly to the Voice Chat and / or Video Chat features of GTalk correct?

Comment: @lazyPower - good question, only gtalk is the text chat, and google voice is the voice chat :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Empathy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/Empathy) [image: Install Empathy], the default chat client, supports google talk.

Answer (score 6):

[**Pidgin**](http://pidgin.im/)

> [Pidgin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/Pidgin) [image: Install Pidgin] is a chat program which lets you log in to accounts on multiple chat networks simultaneously. This means that you can be chatting with friends on MSN, talking to a friend on Google Talk, and sitting in a Yahoo chat room all at the same time.

You can access it from Applications -> Internet menu.
At first run it asks you add your accounts you can add you gtalk account through that.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is that for calling also?

Comment: You can't call this way, only chat.

Comment: you need to enable video and voice suport in plugins to use gtalk video and voice service

Comment: Instructions for configuring GTalk with Pidgin: [Google apps accounts](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=49147), [regular accounts](http://support.google.com/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=24073)

Answer (score 3):

[Kopete](http://packages.ubuntu.com/kopete) [image: Install kopete]

For KDE desktop, Kopete is the default chat application, and supports GTalk.

Answer (score 1):

Gtalk uses the jabber protocol, which any number of non-web clients can use. I for example use iChat on mac.

Comment: Right - but what about voice & video?

Answer (score 0):

Or may you want to try this trick, it works almost equal to gtalk for windows.You can make audio/video calls also http://tutafuta.com/2011/05/25/how-to-use-gtalk-on-linux-or-mac/